# Cannot Use Charles Proxy after update the phones to Android 9

Tags: android, proxy, android-9.0-pie

I updated my test devices (Samsung galaxy Note 9 and galaxy S9+) to Android 9.
Now I am not able to use Charles proxy to grep any traffic.
I have updated my Charles Proxy to the latest version 4.2.8 (MAC)
And I have configured proxy on Wifi setting like old days.

Note: Charles Proxy was working fine before update (Android 8.0 for S9+, 8.1 for Note 9)

Comment: I cannot reproduce this issue after 1 night, both http and https can be seen now. Same Device, Same network, it seems it was some network connection issue...

Answer (score 8):

[SSL Certificates | Charles](https://www.charlesproxy.com/documentation/using-charles/ssl-certificates/)

> As of Android N, you need to add configuration to your app in order to have it trust the SSL certificates generated by Charles SSL Proxying. This means that you can only use SSL Proxying with apps that you control.

Add a file res/xml/network_security_config.xml to your app:

```
<network-security-config> 
  <debug-overrides> 
    <trust-anchors> 
      <!-- Trust user added CAs while debuggable only -->
      <certificates src="user" /> 
    </trust-anchors> 
  </debug-overrides> 
</network-security-config>
```

Then add a reference to this file in your app's manifest, as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest ... >
    <application android:networkSecurityConfig="@xml/network_security_config" ... >
        ...
    </application>
</manifest>
```

After you have reinstalled charles proxy, recreate the certificate.

Answer (score 1):

If you have root access to your phone you can do the same that was done [here](https://blog.ropnop.com/configuring-burp-suite-with-android-nougat/) and add the charles proxy certificate to the system trusted certificates of the phone

Comment: even if you don't have root access to your phone, you can modify the specific APK you want to MitM, it's explained in the same article @fuomag9 suggests

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem recently with my Galaxy Note FE and 8 updated to Android Pie. However I managed to solve it by assigning a Static IP to the phone, apart from the manual proxy. Give it a try.

Answer (score -1):

The issue was with Android OS update (version 9) on Samsung Note and Galaxy devices, which they fixed recently in the last patch update.

Answer (score -5):

Install Charles Root Certificate:

[image: install charles root certificate]